# Change value format in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I debug code under VS 2010 I  see all vales in the following format

**0x000003**

How to turn off that format and see "normal" values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the debug toolbar and there is a button named "Hex", try clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

right click in the "Locals" or "Autos" view and switch "Hexadecimal Display" on and off as you like it.